# Dropdown list bind using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery-ui

I would like this type of binding in dropdownbox

-Any `Bachelor's` Degree-
BCA
BCOM

-Any `Master's` Degree-
MCA
MBA

-Any Degree-
PGCDA

Comment: I think you need to post some code. Where does jquery come into it? That is a client side language and asp.net is server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve using below, This is just example you cam change as your requirement

```
function OnSuccess(data) {       
        $('#ddlAccessLevelGroup').empty();
        var d = data;
        var dropdown = $('#ddlAccessLevelGroup');
        var GroupCode = "";
        var optGroup;

        for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
            if (d[i].GroupCode.toString() != GroupCode) {
                optGroup = $("<optgroup style='background-color:#94c0d2' />");
                optGroup.attr('label', d[i].GroupCode.toString());
            }
            GroupCode = d[i].GroupCode.toString();
            optGroup.append(
                    $('<option></option>').val(d[i].AccessLvlId.toString()).html(d[i].AccessLvlName.toString())
                );
            dropdown.append(optGroup);
        }    
    }
```

C# Code

```
public IQueryable<AccessLevel> TestGetAccessLevelData()
        {
            IQueryable<AccessLevel> AccessLevelGrp = null;

            IQueryable<AccessLevel> AccessLevel = from a in unitOfWork.ACCESS_LEVEL_RXRepository.Get()
                                                         select new AccessLevel
                                                    {
                                                        AccessLvlId = a.ACCESS_LVL_ID_RX,
                                                        AccessLvlName = a.ACCESS_LVL_NAME,
                                                        GroupCode = "Group A"
                                                    };

            IQueryable<AccessLevel> AccessLevel1 = from a in unitOfWork.ACCESS_LEVEL_RXRepository.Get()
                                                         select new AccessLevel
                                                         {
                                                             AccessLvlId = a.ACCESS_LVL_ID_RX,
                                                             AccessLvlName = a.ACCESS_LVL_NAME,
                                                             GroupCode = "Group B"
                                                         };                      

            var result = AccessLevel.Union(AccessLevel1);          
            return result.OrderBy(c=> c.GroupCode);
        }
```